# Creating a relative path for a simple app

Tags: node.js, json, path, relative-path

index.js

```
var fs = require('fs');

var obj = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('/Users/amelie/Documents/project/config.json', 'utf8'));
```

I compile this file into an app called test-macOS using `$pkg index.js` . This app successively reads data from a file called config.json inside the project folder.

However, the config.json file and test-macOS file inside the project folder will be download by other users (by downloading the project folder). This will change the absolute path **/Users/amelie/Documents/project/config.json'** of the file config.json that the app must read. Is there a way to define a path that will be the same for all users so that this file can be successively read using the app by all users that download this project folder ?

I tried using the relative path ./config.JSON but it seems that once I compile index.js I get an error

```
/Users/amelie/Documents/project/test-macos ;

exit; internal/fs/utils.js:312 throw err; ^ 

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open './config.JSON
```

like if the test-macOS file and config.json were not in the same directory (they are in the same 'project' folder however)

Answer (score 0):

In nodejs there is an environmental variable you can use called `__dirname` which gives you the absolute path of the directory you are in. So if you are trying to get the path of config.json and it is in the same directory as your project, it should look something like `__dirname + "/config.json"`
(2 underscores before dirname)

Comment: I cannot use __dirname since once I compile my file and execute the script the directory becomes the directory of the exe file. What else can you suggest me?

Comment: /Users/amelie/Documents/project/test-macos is there a way to access only project/. Config.js because there is nothing in project/test-macos. So to access /config.json/test-macos?

Comment: Or a way to change files included inside the executable?

Comment: I copied your two lines of code with only the relative path "./config.json" and added a console.log to output the content of my dummy config.json. I compiled using `pkg index.js --target node14-linux-x64` and it seemed to work fine after running the executable. I even moved the executable and the config.json file to different directories on my system and it still works.

Comment: mmhh maybe an issue with how macos is compiled